# Data to Int / String in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm working with BLE device. Device is sending values in specific UUID.
Here is my code for converting Data to Int or String for display.

```
...
else if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: UUID_CHANGEIN_BATTERY_LEVEL) {
//            let battery = UInt32(bigEndian: ((characteristic.value?.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }) ?? 0))
            let array : [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0]
            var data = Data(bytes: array)
            if characteristic.value != nil {
                data.append(characteristic.value!)
            }
            let battery = UInt32(bigEndian: ((data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }) ?? 0))
            print("battery level changed\nNew level is \(getInt(fromData: characteristic.value!, start: 0))!")
//            lblBattery.text = (String(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "0") + "%"
            lblBattery.text = "\(getInt(fromData: characteristic.value!, start: 0))%"

        }
...
func getInt(fromData data: Data, start: Int) -> Int32 {
        let intBits = data.withUnsafeBytes({(bytePointer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Int32 in
            bytePointer.advanced(by: start).withMemoryRebound(to: Int32.self, capacity: 4) { pointer in
                return pointer.pointee
            }
        })
        return Int32(bigEndian: intBits)
//        return Int32(littleEndian: intBits)
    }
```

I've checked in BLE Scanner iOS app, that is displaying `0x2b01` as value and it also display 43 as a battery %. 
I wrote 3-4 kind of code as you see above.
But none of them are giving me 43 as a value.

Please help me find where I've done something wrong or which I'm missing to meet my requirement.

Comment: are u sure, the CBCharateristic value is 0x2b01 and battery = 43%?

Comment: Yes, I've checked on other app i.e. BLEScanner and even also provided in Device integration manual that data will be in hex format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

swift 3

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

   let value = [UInt8](characteristic.value!)

   print("Battery ", value[0], "%")
}
```

Comment: Correct I did same yesterday, and came here to answer. But you already gave same.